# Angular: Getting a second value of a json file based on a select input

Tags: json, angular

I have this json:

```
 [
{"country" : "Afghanistan","city" : "Kabul"},
{"country" : "Albania","city" : "Tirana"},
{"country" : "Algeria","city" : "Alger"},
```

And I want to have a select that when choosing a country, I get the city displayed

My service:

```
getCountries(name?: string, city?: string, expectancy?: string, polulation?: string, government?: string) {
    let cities = this.http.get('assets/capitals.json'); -> this is the one called
    let language = this.http.get('assets/languages.json');
    return forkJoin([cities, language]);

  }
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.weatherService.getCountries()
      .subscribe(dataList => {
        this.cities = dataList[0]

        console.log(this.capitals)

        this.population = dataList[1]
        console.log(this.cities, this.population)
      })

  }
  onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue)
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
            <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" class="form-control">

                <option style="color:black" *ngFor="let c of cities" value="{{c.country}}">{{c.country}}</option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It sounds very simple but something is missing. If it were an API I would pick up the select value and make another call with that value on url, but like this, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is logging the value of the "select" component which in your case happens to be the country. If you want to display the country but use the city as the value, you simply change the following in the HTML:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
    <option style="color:black" *ngFor="let c of cities" value="{{c.city}}">{{c.country}}</option>
</select>
```

Using the above, the country will be displayed but your "onChange" function will log the city value. If you wish to do something else with the city value, you can do so in your onChange function.